# Creating an alarm application for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, alarm

I have an idea for a unique alarm application on the iPhone.  But at the moment the only way I can see of initiating the alarm is by leaving the app running all night getting it to poll for the current time.  Is there anyway to make an app "wake up" or initiate at a certain time.  I know I can use [push or local notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) but they require user input before loading my app. Thinking about it I could leave my app on all night, but literally doing nothing (saving battery if not being charged) and then subscribe to a local notification for the alarm itself.

Alternatively, can I make the iPhone run my app when an alarm sounds so I don't have to deal with alarm settings at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your only option is to use either Local or Push notifications.

Comment: They cannot automatically wake your app up though can they? So my app would have to be running to action them?

Comment: No, only the user can decide if an app should be started (with the acception of a VOIP app). And no you can use the local notification to display an message and play a sound. If you want more the you most be started by pressing the view option on the notification. Your app will be informed which notification started the app.

Answer (score 1):

I think using event kit framework add event in default iPhone calender.

Comment: A bit interesting, but the docs state that the event kit framework means that your events must show up in the calendar or reminders app. You don't want morning call events to show up in the calendar now right.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ConfiguringAlarms/ConfiguringAlarms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765-CH6-SW1